# iOS UIButton, setEnabled and button.hidden not working

Tags: ios, events, uibutton, ibaction, iboutlet

I've tried all the answers I found on SO, so either I have a different problem or the heat got to my brain.

Anyway, I have a UIButton on a storyboard, it's linked to an IBAction called _cameraButtonPress (the UIButton is called _cameraButton).  When the button is pressed I want to disable the button for a time, so I immediately call [sender setEnabled:NO]; and this works fine.  However, in a different function which saves out the image, on successful save I use [_cameraButton.setEnabled:YES];  This does not work.

If I replace sender with _cameraButton in the function called by the IBAction, this also does not work.  I have the UIButton linked with an IBOutlet.

I can post code, but it's quite a big project now, here are the relevant bits:

In the header...

```
IBOutlet UIButton *_cameraButton;
```

The IBAction...

```
- (IBAction) _cameraButtonPress:(id)sender {

[sender setEnabled:NO];  //stops button responding to touch events
```

Further on down in a different function:

```
} else {
    NSLog(@"colour image saved successfully");
    [_cameraButton setEnabled:YES];


}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: As a test, add a line of code in _cameraButtonPress: `if(sender == _cameraButton) { NSLog(@"Sender is _cameraButton") }`  If not, then the button wasn't linked properly and that's your problem.

Comment: Ye, linkage is fine, the log shows that the _cameraButton is the sender.  Cheers though :

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons connected to _cameraButton?

Comment: No, one link only.  I'm really confused by this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you have connected _cameraButton with the `UIButton`? Try logging _cameraButton to see if it holds a reference to a valid object.

```
NSLog(@"%@", _cameraButton);
```

Comment: Hello.  Yes, the connections were all good.  It turns out the problem was one I doubt anyone could solve, a quick close and re-open of the project solved it.  So I'm guessing it was a quirk with Xcode.  It's been bugging out on me a lot recently.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer is the most logical problem.

As an aside, the underscore convention is used to differentiate between ivars and properties. Thus, you would have a property something like (for ARC):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *cameraButton;
```

And, if you needed the ivar, your `@synthesize` statement could be:

```
@synthesize cameraButton = _cameraButton;
```

This is probably less relevant with buttons than other properties, but good practice suggests underscores for ivars associated with declared properties, not for the properties themselves.

See [Naming Properties and Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html) in *Apple's Coding Guidelines for Cocoa.*

Comment: Thanks, I started with underscores for some reason I can't remember now, but yes it would be good for me to stick with convention.  I'll change them.